# change multiple image size using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following html :

```
    <div id="ProductImages" align="center">
     <div id="divProductPicZ72" class="c1"></div>

      <div id="divProductPic72">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=
        "popupimg('images/Product/large/72.jpg');"><img border="0" id="ProductPic72" name=
        "ProductPic72" class="c2" onclick="popupimg('images/Product/large/72.jpg')" title=
        "Click here to view larger image" src="images/product/medium/72_1_.png" alt=
        "SK100DS" /></a>
      </div>

    <img border="0" class="c2" onclick="setcolorpicidx_72(1);" alt="Show Picture 1"
          src="images/PRODUCT/icon/72_1_.png" /><img border="0" class="c2" onclick=
          "setcolorpicidx_72(2);" alt="Show Picture 2" src=
          "images/PRODUCT/icon/72_2_.png" />

    <img border="0" class="c2" onclick="setcolorpicidx_72(3);" alt="Show Picture 3" src=
          "images/PRODUCT/icon/72_3_.png" />

    <img border="0" class="c2" onclick="setcolorpicidx_72(4);" alt="Show Picture 4" src=
          "images/PRODUCT/icon/72_4_.png" />

    <img border="0" class="c2" onclick="setcolorpicidx_72(5);" alt="Show Picture 5" src=
          "images/PRODUCT/icon/72_5_.png" />

    <img border="0" class="c2" onclick="setcolorpicidx_72(6);" alt="Show Picture 6" src=
          "images/PRODUCT/icon/72_6_.png" />

    <img border="0" class="c2" onclick="setcolorpicidx_72(7);" alt="Show Picture 7" src=
          "images/PRODUCT/icon/72_7_.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The div `<div id="divProductPic72">` following by the  tag is the main picture and when you click on it i have code that pops it up larger in a new window.

I would like to inject some jquery to make all the images smaller as they are the thumbnails. They are after the above div.

id like to make them 100x100 thumbnails.

I have tried this:

```
$("div#ProductImages img").css("width", "100px");
```

Not sure if thats correct?

Comment: It looks good. Does it work as you intend it to do? What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select only direct children and not all ancestors use the following snippet

```
 $("#ProductImages>img")
```

or

```
 $("#ProductImages").children("img")
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do both dimensions:

```
$("div#ProductImages img").css("width", "100px");
$("div#ProductImages img").css("height", "100px");
```

Comment: the only thing, i would rather change selector `$("#ProductImages img")` or `$("#ProductImages").find("img")`

Comment: You don't need .find() in this case. Keep it simple.

Comment: it is equaly simple, in second case there is not selector parsing

Comment: the problem with this solution is that i have another img inside the parent div which is also resizing. I dont want this happening. The div is wrapped in an <A> tag.

Comment: @sp-1986 then use either `$("#ProductImages>img")` or `$("#ProductImages").children("img")`

Comment: @vittore you should make an answer so i can accept it, `$("#ProductImages").children("img")` was my solution